# Is there a way to print all the data stored in Milvus DB

Tags: java, milvus

I want to print all the data that is stored in Milvus without any filters in java.

I tried going through the Milvus official documentation but couldn't find anything that works without filters. I am not looking for hacky that build filters such that all the data is returned.

Comment: What specifically is the problem you have. Based on the code on https://milvus.io/docs/query.md, I would expect building a query without calling `withExpr` or `withFilter` will do just that. Can you provide a [mre] with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Do either of these approaches work?

1. dump a collection as-is with https://github.com/zilliztech/milvus-backup

- or -

2. We have example Python code to create an iterator over the collection to read out all the rows https://milvus.io/docs/with_iterators.md